# Screen up time in desktop

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, kernel

I might be sounding like a noob while asking this question but I really want to know how can I get the time from when my screen is on. Not the system up time but the screen up time. I want to use this time in a python app. So please tell me if there is any way to get that. Thanks in advance.

Edit- I want to get the time from when the display is black due to no activity and we move mouse or press a key and screen comes up, the display is up, the user is able to read and/or able to edit a document or play games.

OS is windows .

Comment: Define screen uptime: is it all the time the screen is not in standby (so showing desktop or login/lock screen or screensaver) or only a more specific state? And, what OS?

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS `ioreg` might have the information you're looking for.

`ioreg -n IODisplayWrangler -r IODisplayWrangler -w 0 | grep IOPowerManagement`